# How to use RoboBrowser to click a button

Tags: python

how can i click a button with RoboBrowser?

this is the html code:

```
<div id="DivDati" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-             content ui-corner-bottom">
         <p><a style="margin:20px;" class="button" href="javascript:EsportaConfrontoCanali(false);">Esporta</a></p>
        <!-- Tabella -->
        <table style="width:800px;margin:auto;" class="confrontoTabelle">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <th>Selezionare i valori e premere "Filtra"</th>
                </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        <!-- Fine tabella -->
    </div>
```

Comment: RoboBrowser won't work in this case. It doesn't support JS or any other dynamic browsing features. Use [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org) instead.

Answer (score 2):

As Fmaz mentioned, you can use Selenium to do that.

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'set your website URL here'

driver = webdriver.Chrome("Set your path to chrome driver here")
#path example: /home/username/Downloads/chromedriver

driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_class_name('button').click()
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually this could be done using RoboBrowser!
The button click element is actually contains an href link that could be found and used to redirect:

```
 browser.follow_link(browser.get_link("Esporta"))
```